# Opa : customize bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, opa

I'd like to use the bindings for Bootstrap provided by Opa, but I want to use a customized version of Bootstrap, i.e. my own css.

For instance, I'd like to change the background color of hero-unit.

How can I do that ?

Thaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a css file and overwrite bootstrap css classes.

Here for example how to add a css to your app:

```
Server.start(
    Server.http,
    [ {resources: @static_resource_directory("resources")}
      , {register: ["resources/css.css"]}
      , {title: "Chat", page:start }
    ]
);
```

(extracted from http://doc.opalang.org/manual/Hello--chat)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only Opa bootstrap widgets [WBootsrap](http://doc.opalang.org/module/stdlib.widgets.bootstrap/WBootstrap), without the embed CSS, just `import stdlib.widgets.bootstrap`.

Then, use Cedrics' method to include your own Bootstrap CSS.